# Unique IDs for Each Extended Class

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a baseCollection and baseModel in Backbone written in Coffeescript, like so:

```
class Collection extends Backbone.Collection

  constructor: (attrs = {}, options = {}) ->
   return attrs if attrs instanceof Collection
   return self if self = constructorCheck attrs, options

   super attrs
   constructorCreate @, attrs, options
```

All models / collections extend from these base units. Is it possible to create a uniqueID for each class that extends off these base classes? Like:

```
class Animals extends Collection --> given a uniqueID
class Monkeys extends Animals --> given a uniqueID
```

The goal is to filter collections / models from a Universal Collection Store that is caching all my models and collections. I want to recreate the model store as described in this 
[article](http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2012/06/building-the-next-soundcloud/)

Comment: Do you mean something like [`cid`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) but for collections?

Comment: Yea for constructors though - not the instances

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite follow but I'm guessing you're trying to create a way to access singleton instances of collections of Animals and Monkeys across views?

If this is the case, here is my first take at it with coffeescript -- not exactly the same pattern it sounds like you're looking for but an option in coffee/javascript

```
class Registry
  find: (t) ->
    lookup = @lookup ||= {}
    lookup[t] ||= new t

class People extends Backbone.Collection
class Things extends Backbone.Collection

r = new Registry

p = r.find(People)
p2 = r.find(People)
t = r.find(Things)
t2 = r.find(Things)

if p != p2 || t != t2 || p == t
  alert('failure')
else
  alert('pass')
```

However, to answer your question a little closer to how I first read it -- here is how you could generate a unique id per extended class. I'm not entirely sure this is what you really want though as each collection is its own instance/ wont be synchronized across views (however, all collections of the same 'type' will have the same 'myId').

```
index = 0
lookup = {}

class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  constructor: ->
    f = arguments.callee.caller
    if(lookup[f]?)
      @myId = lookup[f]
    else
      lookup[f] = index
      @myId = index
      index += 1

class People extends MyCollection
class Things extends MyCollection

p = new People()
p2 = new People()
t = new Things()
t2 = new Things()

if p.myId != p2.myId || t.myId != t2.myId || p.myId == t.myId
  alert('failure')
else
  alert('pass')
```

I myself would probably not take this latter approach but it should work.